# Standard Bibtex example code does not work

Tags: bibtex

I am new to Latex and I am trying to incoorperate references/bibliography in my document. First I want to get the code working that I got from here http://www.bibtex.org/Using/

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

The .bib file is as follows

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
   author = "Nobody Jr",
   title = "My Article",
   year = "2006" }
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't show my list of references and when it should cite

```
~\cite{Nobody06}
```

then it just displays

> [?]

If have read that this has something to do with bibtex not running the right files. I should see this in my blg file. But I have not been able to find my blg file yet.

It's probably a super simple solution but I haven't found it.
I am using TexWorks and MikTex.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you run bibtex at all? texworks has a menu entry for it. (typeset -> bibtex). Did you rerun pdflatex?

Comment: OT: Why have you got a brace group after `\bibliography{mybib}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked! I had to run bibtex twice and then pdflatex. Now I have the document as it should be. Thank you for this! Sorry for the simple question..

Comment: @JosephWright This was exactly how I found the code so I didn't changed it yet. It seems unnecessary yes

Comment: `\bibliography{mybib}{}` is something I am not familiar with...I am used to a format like `\bibliography{mybib}` that means that the `bib` file that will be used is named "mybib.bib"... also usually this command follows the `\bibliographystyle` command. Edit: I suppose that the second `{}` just left there by mistake and you can remove it... I dont think it creates a problem... But doesn't belong there

Comment: On that basis, it's a dupe of the generic 'question mark' question.